# How to use compressed textures (eg .dds) in PixiJS version 5?

Tags: javascript, compression, pixi.js

I would like to use compressed textures in my PixiJS application (.dds DXT-1 files). For PixiJS version 4 there is a plugin: https://github.com/pixijs/pixi-compressed-textures. Unfortunately, this does not work with PixiJS version 5. Is there any other way to use dds files in PixiJS version 5?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I answer my own question :-) Use this plugin: [PixiJS Compressed Textures](https://github.com/pixijs/pixi-compressed-textures)